# Definitive list of possible reasons NSManagedObjectContext save might fail

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

**TL;DR version**: is there a definitive list of possible reasons that `-[NSManagedObjectContext save:]` could fail? I'm looking in `CoreDataErrors.h`, but it's not clear which of the keys relate to `NSDetailedErrorsKey`.

**Background:** I'm maintaining a shipping app written in a combination of Swift and Objective-C. It uses `JSQCoreDataKit`. Someone else wrote the code originally.

We have a production crash that we have not been able to reproduce. We can tell from the stacktrace that it is crashing in an error handler following an `NSManagedObjectContext` save failure with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` trying to log the `NSError` to the console. The save failure is on a child context and we know the model class which was being modified at the time.

Hence we can tell that the save is failing, but we have no detailed information about the reason for the save failure.

We want to work backwards from the reason for the save failure, in the hopes of working out a reproduction for the crash, in order to test any potential fixes.

The crash is actually a side effect of the save failure. So although we want to fix the crash, we also need to work out the reason for the save failure.

For 95% of users, the save happens without problems.

The model has some non-optional fields and the data comes from JSON parsed from a server response. At this stage we have no reason to suspect the server is sending us bad data.

**Does anyone know of a definitive list of possible reasons for a save failure that we could work through, eliminating options?**

So far, I'm aware of:

- validation failure e.g. a missing a required value, or a value outside specified max/min values in the model.
- a possible save conflict (see `NSPersistentStoreSaveConflictsErrorKey`). But it's not clear if it's possible to have this when saving from a child context to a parent context.

Comment: Have you seen the [Core Data Constants](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Miscellaneous/CoreData_Constants/) reference?  Not sure if it adds anything more than the .h file.

Comment: Failing to save is not the same as a crash. Validation failures, for example, are not inherently crashing-- though your code's response to them might be. And crashes might occur for reasons not directly related to Core Data, such as memory management errors that happen to occur after a failed save.

Comment: Thanks but I'm aware they are two separate things - apologies if my post did not make it sufficiently clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should *never* be a failure `-save:` with no error.  Every time I have seen that situation it was my fault in my code somewhere.

Can you update the question with showing the code around the error location?

The possible failures of a save are:

- Merge failure (most common)
- Validation failure (less common)
- No store defined in the `NSPersistentStore`
- A `nil` `NSManagedObjectContext` (this would present the case you describe)

All of those except for the last will produce an error object to interrogate.